# Capturing regex group inside of template literal as function argument

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I have a set of dates in one format and I need to convert those dates into another one.

input: `<month>/<day>/<year>`

output: `<day>/<month>/<year>` - additionally I need to pad months and days with `0` if it contain only one character.

I have created regular expression to match given date format. Then I wanted to modify that date using `String.prototype.replace` and modify captured groups by passing them into function directly inside of template literal as a second argument of `replace` method.

The problem I am facing is that it doesn't work as I would expect. In some cases function `pad` correctly pads the date, in other cases it doesn't. More precisely, I would expect second console log to be `12`, but the result is `012`.

```js
const pad = date => date.length === 2 ? date : '0' + date;

const normalizeDate = date => {
  const regex = /(?<month>\d{1,2})\/(?<day>\d{1,2})\/(?<year>\d{4})/;

  // pad string of length 1 works correctly (expected '01'/ result '01')
  console.log(date.replace(regex, `${pad('$<month>')}`));

  // pad sting of length 2 doesn't (expected '12' / result '012')
  console.log(date.replace(regex, `${pad('$<day>')}`));

  // test shows that <day> = 12
  console.log(date.replace(regex, `$<day>`));

  // padding 12 directly works (expected '12' / result '12') 
  console.log(pad('12'));

  return date.replace(regex, `${pad('$<month>')}-${pad('$<day>')}-$<year>`);
}

const date = '1/12/2014';
normalizeDate(date);
```

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong with that code?

Comment: This doesn't make sense, `${pad('$<day>')}`. You're padding `$<day>` string, not `12`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$<day>` named backreferences can only be used in string replacement patterns. Since you need to modify the captures, you need to use anonymous methods:

```
.replace(regex, (_,month,day,year) => `${pad(month)}`)
```

Here, in parentheses, you must define the variables for the whole match and for the capturing groups. So, basically, you need not the new ECMAScript 2018 regex enhancement since you can use regular numbered capturing groups here, too.

See the updated demo:

```js
const pad = date => date.length === 2 ? date : '0' + date;

const normalizeDate = date => {
  const regex = /(?<month>\d{1,2})\/(?<day>\d{1,2})\/(?<year>\d{4})/;

  // pad string of length 1 works correctly (expected '01'/ result '01')
  console.log(date.replace(regex, (_,month,day,year) => pad(month)));

  // pad sting of length 2 doesn't (expected '12' / result '012')
  console.log(date.replace(regex, (_,month,day,year) => pad(day)));

  // test shows that <day> = 12
  console.log(date.replace(regex, "$<day>"));

  // padding 12 directly works (expected '12' / result '12') 
  console.log(pad('12'));

  return date.replace(regex, (_,month,day,year) => `${pad(month)}-${pad(day)}-${year}`);
}

const date = '1/12/2014';
console.log(normalizeDate(date));
```

Comment: So there's not much point to the `?<month>` names for the capture groups, except as self-documentation.

Comment: `\`${pad(month)}\`` is the same as `pad(month)`.

Comment: Ok, pruned it a little more.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks.